# wireshark for network analysis without violating any privacy policy

Tags: networking, monitoring, wireshark, analysis, traffic

I would like to know the **network analysis** in the network (traffic monitoring) eg: packet size, webites visited etc.

My requirement was met with wireshark. I would like to know that while using wireshark,
Does it capture the user credentials that are given by the user? (seen in certain websites).

**If yes** please suggest me any other tool that can do the same without violating any privacy policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what options on wireshark you are using, but it can easily do full packet capture which will contain all kinds of sensitive data. If you are just looking at packet headers then you wouldn't have this issue. Wireshark is not really a monitoring tool, you might want to look at the open source tools like ntop/ntopng which will do a better job and be always on.

Why do you care about packet size? Never heard of anyone really wanting that data :)